# A more efficient Regex or alternative?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a file with a little over a million lines.

```
 {<uri::rdfserver#null> <uri::d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e> <uri::TickerDailyPriceVolume> "693702"^^<xsd:long>}
 {<uri::rdfserver#null> <uri::d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e> <uri::TickerDailyPriceId> <uri::20fb8f7d-30ef-dd11-a78d-001f29e570a8>}
```

Each line is a statement.

```
struct Statement
    string C;
    string S;
    string P;
    string O;
    string T;
```

Currently I'm using a TextReader in a while loop and parsing each line with a regular expression:

```
Regex lineParse = new Regex(@"[^<|\""]*\w[^>\""]*", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

It takes quite awhile to do this parsing and I'm hoping someone can point me to a more efficient parsing strategy.

Some lines have 5 matchs and some 4.  Here is how each line is parsed:

```
{<uri::rdfserver#null> <uri::d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e> <uri::TickerDailyPriceVolume> "693702"^^<xsd:long>}

Statement()
    C = uri::rdfserver#null
    S = uri::d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
    P = uri::TickerDailyPriceVolume
    O = 693702
    T = xsd:long

{<uri::rdfserver#null> <uri::d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e> <uri::TickerDailyPriceId> <uri::20fb8f7d-30ef-dd11-a78d-001f29e570a8>}

Statement()
    C = uri::rdfserver#null
    S = uri::d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
    P = uri::TickerDailyPriceId
    O = uri::20fb8f7d-30ef-dd11-a78d-001f29e570a8
```

Additional information from the comments: "The poor performance I was seeing is actually due to a conditional break-point that I had set in the code. Without that break-point everything is pretty fast. Still if anyone has any improvement ideas I would be interested" -Eric Schoonover

Comment: The poor performance I was seeing is actually due to a conditional breakpoint that I had set in the code.  Without that breakpoint everything is pretty fast.  Still if anyone has any improvement ideas I would be interested :)

Comment: you might what to add that info to your post, so people know your not looking for speed anymore.

Comment: I still am looking for speed, it's just that the regex I posted isn't necessarily as slow as I thought it was.

Comment: I'd be interested to know how your approach compares to those offered by @sixlettervariables.  I would expect the Split approach to be noticeably faster.

Comment: By the way, in this character class - [^<|\""] - you don't need the pipe or the backslash. The OR is implied, and double-quotes in C# verbatim strings are escaped by doubling them, which you've already done.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The fastest (as shown below) is a simple string split:

```
line.Split(new char[] { '{', '<', '>', '}', ' ', '^', '"' },
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The next fastest is an anchored regular expression (ugly):

```
Regex lineParse
    = new Regex(@"^\{(<([^>]+)>\s*){3,4}(""([^""]+)""\^\^<([^>]+)>\s*)?\}$",
                RegexOptions.Compiled);
Match m = lineParse.Match(line);
if (m.Groups[2].Captures.Count == 3)
{
    Data data = new Data { C = m.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value,
        S = m.Groups[2].Captures[1].Value, P = m.Groups[2].Captures[2].Value,
        O = m.Groups[4].Value, T = m.Groups[5].Value };
} else {
    Data data = new Data { C = m.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value,
        S = m.Groups[2].Captures[1].Value, P = m.Groups[2].Captures[2].Value,
        O = m.Groups[2].Captures[3].Value, T = String.Empty };
}
```

Timings for 1M lines of random data (String.Split as the baseline):

```
Method                #1  Wall (Diff)       #2  Wall (Diff)
------------------------------------------------------------
line.Split                3.6s (1.00x)         3.1s (1.00x)
myRegex.Match             5.1s (1.43x)         3.3s (1.10x)
itDependsRegex.Matches    6.8s (1.88x)         4.4s (1.44x)
stateMachine              8.4s (2.34x)         5.6s (1.82x)
alanM.Matches             9.1s (2.52x)         7.8s (2.52x)
yourRegex.Matches        18.3s (5.06x)        12.1s (3.90x)
```

**Updated to include @AlanM and @itdepends regular expressions.** It appears that Regex.Matches is slower than Regex.Match, however, the more context clues you give the parser, the better it performs. The single negative character class used by @AlanM is the simplest to read, yet slower than the most cryptic (mine). Hats off to @itdepends for the simplest regex that produces the fastest time. Ok, and while I thought it would be crazy to write a state machine to parse the line, it actually doesn't perform poorly at all...kudos to @RexM for the suggestion. I've also added times from my Q6600 at home (#2) v. an older Xeon at work (#1).

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes a state machine is significantly faster than a Regex.

Comment: +1, I was going to scoff at your answer, until I wrote it up myself. It isn't the worst, nor is it the best. Surprisingly decent for the amount of work required...

Comment: Since regex's are just a special case of a state-machine, with the right optimizations, you should be able to beat any regex engine.

Answer (score 2):

After some testing I came up with:

```
@"<(?<capture>[^>]+)>|""(?<capture>[^""]+)"""
```

The value needs to be acessed with match.Groups[1].Value.

In my unscientific test it was around 75-80% faster then the one in the original question.

**Match vs Matches**

In production I usually use Match, but used Matches for the above.  I've never really considered the performance implications so did a little testing, so with exactly the **same regex**:

```
for(Match match = regex.Match(input); match.Success; match = match.NextMatch())
// min 5.01 sec
// max 5.15 sec

foreach(Match match in regex.Matches(input))
// min 5.66 sec
// max 6.07 sec
```

So Match certainly can be faster than Matches.

Comment: Added timing for yours to mine, shaves roughly 3s from OP's regex

Comment: +1, I think it is a combination of backtracking and context provided in the regular expression. The angle brackets give your regex context that just a negative character class would not give.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the regexes that have been offered so far are much more complicated than they need to be.  If @sixlettervariables' Split approach works, Matches should work with this regex:

```
@"[^{}<> ^""]+"
```

But I would still expect the String.Split approach to be faster.

Comment: I think what makes String.Split faster is that it doesn't use regexes.  Try it with Regex.Split.

Comment: Oh, I see you're talking about Matches vs. Match performance.  But you're only doing one match for each line, and your regex has virtually no backtracking opportunities.  All the others have to perform several matches per line.